# What effects are going on here?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, guitar-effects, effects-pedal

I'd like to recreate the sound in guitar lick of this song (lick at 4:00).

I was wondering whether anyone with a keen ear could let me know what effects/pedals might be being used here. I love the ethereal sound it has and would like to create something similar for a piece I am putting together.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi - from a very basic point of view, and on first listen, It sounds like a straightforward distorted lead guitar sound with a bit of (possibly delay and) reverb, with some contribution from a clean, delayed/reverbed sound every couple of bars...  on what point were you looking for more detail?

Comment: I thought similarly to topo morto. It sounds like an electric guitar (with distortion) with some reverb. I can't hear anything else in the lead guitar other than that.